# Compress file with QuaZIP

Tags: qt, quazip

I'm looking for some example to zip files in Qt using QuaZIP.
I tried this code but it doesn't work. I received a segmentation fault error.

```
JlCompress::compressFiles(zipfilename,filenames);//zipfilename is a qstring and filenames a QStringList
```

Should I open files before compressing them ?

Comment: What does the function returns? true, false? Did you try with opening all the files to compress before using this function?

Comment: the function returns false
I tried this code 
    for(int i=0;i<filenames.size();i++){
        QFile infile(filenames[0]);
        infile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    }
    QFile outfile(zipfilename);
    outfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    bool test=JlCompress::compressFiles(zipfilename,filenames);
but doesn't work

Comment: You need to inspect what is happening in the function `compressFiles` then

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved,
I removed th quazip installation then I installed it manually:

```
I downloaded the source code from http://sourceforge.net/projects/quazip/files/latest/download
tar xvfz quazip-0.7.1.tar.gz
cd quazip-0.7.1
qmake "PREFIX=/usr/local" "LIBS+=-lz"
make
make install
```

After that i installed the `libquazip-qt5-*` packages using apt get
finally i linked quazip in my pro file using

```
LIBS += -lquazip -lz
```